# Python - Reduce multiple elif who contains 2 conditions

Tags: python-3.x, sonarqube

I try to increase the quality of this code, because Sonarqube doesn't like when there is too much if/elif.

I tried to use "swich case"; but this function is too young for my production environment.
Can i use dictionnary method with 2 conditions ?

This is my code :

```
if letter == "ABC" and orientation == "south" :
    numero = "1"
elif letter == "ABC" and orientation == "east" :
    numero = "2"
elif letter == "EDF" and orientation == "south" :
    numero = "3"
elif letter == "EDF" and orientation == "east" :
    numero = "4"
elif letter == "GHI" and orientation == "south" :
    numero = "5"
elif letter == "GHI" and orientation == "north" :
    numero = "6"
elif letter == "GHI" and orientation == "east" :
    numero = "7"
```

Comment: There is no `switch - case` in Python, also don't worry if your code look like YandereDev's one.

Comment: Maybe you could use a dict to avoid the if/elif ? dictionary = {
    "ABC" : {
        "south" : "1",
        "east" : "2"
    },
    "EDF" : {
        "south" : "3",
        "east" : "4"
    },
    "GHI" : {
        "south" : "5",
        "north" : "6",
        "east" : "7"
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

You can create a mapping between letter, orientation and number and then fetch number from there:

```
values = {
    ("ABC", "south"): "1",
    ("ABC", "east"): "2",
    ("EDF", "south"): "3",
    ("EDF", "east"): "4",
    ("GHI", "south"): "5",
    ("GHI", "north"): "6",
    ("GHI", "east"): "7",
}

letter = "GHI"
orientation = "north"

number = values[(letter, orientation)]
```

If letter and orientation can have invalid values, make sure to enclose the number access in a try/except block:

```
try:
    number = values[(letter, orientation)]
except KeyError as e:
    print(f"No number defined for: {e}")
```